# Why call to StreamPlot terminates kernel each time?

Tags: plotting, kernel, crash

FYI, reported to WRI [**CASE:4288967**]

---

By mistake, I put x range starting from negative to make `StreamPlot` for expression with `Log[x]` in it.

But should this cause the kernel to die?  I am Ok with an empty plot. When using `ParametricPlot` it gives back empty plot, and kernel stays up.

Is this behavior expected or is this a bug?

**Is it possible to catch the error instead of kernel crash?**

For other reasons, I want to keep same range, since this is running inside script over hundreds of different cases, and do not want to change the x-range for each case. But can live with empty plot and an error I can catch instead.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
fTerm = (y (1 + 3 x y^3 Log[x]))/(3 x);
StreamPlot[{1, fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Kernel dies.  But

```
ClearAll[x, y];
fTerm = (y (1 + 3 x y^3 Log[x]))/(3 x);
ParametricPlot[fTerm, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Empty plot. Kernel remains Up.

This is on V12, windows 10.

**update**
I found another example of where kernel crash. This is due to 1/0 (I think). The problem I get no error message printed or anything. Just one loud beep and that is it. This makes it very hard to run the script, since I have to restart the kernel it each time and manually skip the case that caused the crash.

```
ClearAll[x, y]; 
fTerm = -((1 - 3*x^6*y^3)/(3*x^7*y^2)) - (2^(1/3)*(-1 + 6*x^6*y^3))/(3*x^7*y^2*(-2 + 18*x^6*y^3 - 27*x^12*y^6 + 3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-4*x^18*y^9 + 27*x^24*y^12])^(1/3)) + (-2 + 18*x^6*y^3 - 27*x^12*y^6 + 3*Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[-4*x^18*y^9 + 27*x^24*y^12])^(1/3)/(3*2^(1/3)*x^7*y^2); 
StreamPlot[{1, fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I could not catch the error. Adding `Catch` around it has no effect. Kernel just crashed.

Comment: *"should this cause the kernel to die?"*? No, the kernel should die only if instructed to do so, any other crash is a bug. I can reproduce the crash bug in Mathematica 11.3 and 12 on Windows 7 64 . I have highlighted the part of your question that is not off-topic. **How to catch the error before it causes a crash seems and interesting question to me.**

Comment: Same behavior in _v9.0.1_ and _v8.0.4_.

Comment: I get no crash with `{x, -0.89, 2}` but a crash with `-0.895`. Starting at `-0.893` caused the FE to hang. Killing the kernel freed up the FE. (Mac, V12.0)

Comment: Have you reported this to Wolfram Support? Do they acknowledge the bug? 
Can we reproduce this bug on MacOS or Linux?

Comment: Perhaps this is better?: `StreamPlot[
 Boole[Chop@fTerm \[Element] Reals] {1, Re@fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,
   2}]` -- it seems the imaginary parts cancel but `Boole[0.0234375 + 0. I \[Element] Reals]` does not evaluate to a number, for instance. There also seem to be some numerics issues near the y-axis, but adding `WorkingPrecision` causes a `Throw[]`.

Comment: This works better on this example: `StreamPlot[Boole[Im[fTerm] == 0] {1, fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Comment: I thought I tried this, but now this works well for me: `StreamPlot[{1, fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]` -- Perhaps it fails on the other examples and I thought it failed more generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricks used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/203653/4999) also solve this problem. The first seems more robust and does not need `StreamPoints` to be specified:

```
StreamPlot[Boole[fTerm ∈ Reals] {1, fTerm}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]

StreamPlot[{1, ConditionalExpression[#, # ∈ Reals] &@fTerm},
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 StreamPoints -> {{
   {{-1.8, 0.4}, Automatic}, {{-0.6, 1.8}, Automatic},
   {{ 1.8, 0.4}, Automatic}, {{ 0.6, 1.8}, Automatic}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

[Second plot (the original answer) omitted as it is pretty similar. See edit history if curious.]