# why this call to StreamPlot returns unevaluated? (no error message, no beep)

Tags: plotting

I am really baffled by this. Call to `StreamPlot` does not return empty plot, nor an error message, nor a beep. It just return unevaluated.

I do not think I've seen something like this before. What would the cause for this?

Is this expected behavior?

Normally, when a plot can not be generated, either an error is returned or empty plot.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[x, y, f]; 
f = (x*y - Sqrt[-1 + x^2 + y^2])/(-1 + x^2); 
StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

btw, it will plot OK when changing the `-1` to `1` in the above, under the square root:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it seems due to value of the function becomes complex over some region. But normally when this happens, an empty plot is returned, right?

V 12 on windows 10.

Comment: Same on V10.0.1 on Mac OSX 10.12.

Comment: `StreamPlot[{I, x}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` returns unevaluated, so maybe that's what `StreamPlot` does with complexes, except when it crashes. :) -- the docs suggest it might be the way you say: "StreamPlot does not show streamlines at any positions for which the Subscript[v, i] etc. do not evaluate to real numbers."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it should give an error message, perhaps.  I agree with the OP's guess that problem stems from the complex values of the vector field.  It may be that it's because the field is real around the boundaries and then becomes complex.  Here is a workaround:

```
StreamPlot[
 Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[#, # ∈ Reals] & /@ {1, f}],
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

*Update:* Here is another that seems to be more robust. It zeros out the complex-valued parts, and zero vectors are not drawn nor lead to stream lines:

```
StreamPlot[Boole[f ∈ Reals] {1, f}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: very good work around. It also solved the kernel crash in this [why-call-to-streamplot-terminates-kernel-each-time](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203514/why-call-to-streamplot-terminates-kernel-each-time)   so if you like to post your workaround there also, I'll be happy to accept it as well.

Comment: Sorry, but I found a big problem with the above. Now other StreamPlot call crash. Not this example, but other ones when I changed the code to use your trick. Should I open a new question? Here is an example: `f = (6*(2*x^4*y^(2/3) + y))/x; 
StreamPlot[ Evaluate[(ConditionalExpression[#1, Element[#1, Reals]] & ) /@ {1,  f}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`  When I remove the code you added, it works. `StreamPlot[{1, f}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]` So it looks like your method fixed some, but also caused some others not to work. I am using the same command to process hundreds of functions.

Comment: Is it possible to make it work for both examples? Or should I open a new question for the new example that does not work?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.  I get `Hold[Throw[Null, "IntraStepEvaluationException"]]` from the example in the comment. (Mac -- maybe a version difference.)

Comment: Yes. This is what I get also. I am on windows 10, V12. I am trying to find alternative to StreamPlot now, since it seems really buggy. I want to plot direction fields for hundreds of ODE's. VectorPlot does not look as good as StreamPlot. So I'll try to see what else I can find.

Comment: @Nasser See if this gets any mileage: `StreamPlot[ Evaluate[Boole[fff \[Element] Reals] {1, fff}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: I just finished verifying your new method. Now no errors or crashes ! This works much better. You might want to updated both your answers with this new method. Thank you for all the help.